# Symfony/API Platform no UI

Tags: api, symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying out the Platform API framework that works with Symfony.

I am following their docs and trying to set up [the little demo API](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/).

Everything goes OK, at least I think. When I run the server I see no UI I only see this text in my browser:

`{"@context":"\/contexts\/Entrypoint","@id":"\/","@type":"Entrypoint","book":"\/books","person":"\/people","organization":"\/organizations"}`

Anyone knows what goes wrong here?
I am using composer for this little demo.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure to use the version 2 of API Platform (the v1 doesn't have a builtin UI).
To execute the V2, you need PHP 7 or superior.

Do you use the provided Docker image?